# Apply filters to Hough Line Detection

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

In my application, I use Hough Line Detection to detect lines inside an image. What I'm trying to do is to retrieve only the lines that compose the border and the corners of each square of the chessboard. How can I apply filters to obtain a clear view of the lines?
My idea is to apply filters to check the angle between each line(90 degrees) or the distance to get only the lines that count. The final goal will be to obtain the intersection between these lines to get the coordinates of each square.

Code:

```
chessBoard = cv2.imread('img.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(chessBoard,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
dst = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 200)
lines= cv2.HoughLines(dst, 1, math.pi/180.0, 100, np.array([]), 0, 0)
a,b,c = lines.shape
for i in range(a):
    rho = lines[i][0][0]
    theta = lines[i][0][1]
    a = math.cos(theta)
    b = math.sin(theta)
    x0, y0 = a*rho, b*rho
    pt1 = ( int(x0+1000*(-b)), int(y0+1000*(a)) )
    pt2 = ( int(x0-1000*(-b)), int(y0-1000*(a)) )
    cv2.line(chessBoard, pt1, pt2, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

[image]

Comment: The first idea that comes to mind is to find all line intersections and pick 81 points from those that form an approximately uniformly spaced 9x9 grid.

Comment: Could you please show me your idea with an example code? @JussiNurminen

Comment: I don't have time to write the complete code, but I would formulate it as an optimization problem. Create an "ideal" 9x9 grid of points, call it G. Then take all of your line intersections and call this set P. P is much larger than G. Now apply rotation, scaling and translation to G until you get the optimal match between P and G. As the optimization criteria, you could use the average minimal distance between P and G points. Then G gives you the grid you are looking for.
Of course, this requires some familiarity with numerical programming.

Comment: You have some image distortions that cause lines to not be straight. The further from the middle of the image, the stronger this distortion is. This is why you find so many lines for each of the edges of the outside of the board. This distortion will make it harder to find a good grid. An alternative approach would be to find the corners, rather than the lines, and fit a grid to those. Might be easier.